# Wacom Intuos Draw Tablet not detected in System settings and MaptoOutput does nothing

Tags: monitor, tablet, system-settings, wacom, graphics-tablet

So I just installed Ubuntu and my Wacom tablet isn't detected by system settings. My tablet is a Wacom Intuos draw. Except that everything works I just needed the system settings to work so I could map it to monitor so it has the same aspect ratio. Like right now when I draw circle it draws ovals I think you know what I mean. I tried this command: `xsetwacom -v set "Wacom Intuos S 2 Pen stylus" MapToOutput VGA-0` and nothing changed this is what I got in the terminal:

```
... Display is '(null)'.
... 'set' requested for 'Wacom Intuos S 2 Pen stylus'.
... Checking device 'Virtual core pointer' (2).
... Checking device 'Virtual core keyboard' (3).
... Checking device 'Virtual core XTEST pointer' (4).
... Checking device 'Virtual core XTEST keyboard' (5).
... Checking device 'Power Button' (6).
... Checking device 'Power Button' (7).
... Checking device 'Microsoft Wired Keyboard 600' (10).
... Checking device 'Microsoft Wired Keyboard 600' (11).
... Checking device 'Microsoft Wired Keyboard 600' (12).
... Checking device 'Wacom Intuos S 2 Pen stylus' (8).
... Checking device 'Wacom Intuos S 2 Pad pad' (9).
... Device 'Wacom Intuos S 2 Pen stylus' (8) found.
... Found output 'HDMI-0' (disconnnected)
... Found output 'VGA-0' (connected)
... CRTC (0x0) 1280x1024
... Setting CRTC VGA-0
... Remapping to output area 1280x1024 @ 0,0.
... Transformation matrix:
...     [ 1.000000 0.000000 0.000000 ]
...     [ 0.000000 1.000000 0.000000 ]
...     [ 0.000000 0.000000 1.000000 ]
```

Also I had Debian 9 before and the settings worked with no problems on the GNOME Desktop.

Update: I managed to map to area but now I need to find which number should work on my resolution (1280x1024) the number I currently have for the area is 0 0 15200 9500

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I fixed it. I got confused between map to monitor and map to area.

So for those who have the same problem here is what you have to do.

You get the current area of your tablet with this command: `xsetwacom get 8 area`
And you will get 4 numbers. Mine were `0 0 15200 9500` where the smallest number represent the smallest number of your resolution and my resolution is 1280x1024 so 9500 = 1024 and 15200 = over 1280 because the area was wrong to the horizontal. So what I did was dividing 9500 (which was right) by 1024 then multiply the result by 1280 and the number it gave me was the right one so the right area was `0 0 11875 9500`.

So yeah some math is required here.

The system settings still doesn't detect my tablet but now that I know how to do it through the terminal I don't need it in the system settings.