# wacom intuos draw(small) vs genius mousepen i608x for Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Tags: drivers, graphics, tablet, wacom

I am planning on buying one of the graphics tablets mentioned below. So, I need your help to make my decision on Which one to buy?

I have seen other users and pages report of errors while using the "Genius Mousepen i608x" tablets in the Linux system. But because it is less expensive than a Wacom, I am willing to go through *little* trouble of making it work (*not a lot of trouble*).

And since I am a major big fan of Ubuntu (and the Linux environment), I am willing to spend more just so I can use a graphics tablet with it.

The main question I have is **would Genius Mousepen i608x perform the same in Ubuntu as it does with Windows?** Or is there a limitation to its performance? **Would buying a Wacom make my life easier?**

Sidenote: *to all the graphic designers/illustrators/artist out there, would a **small** graphics tablet hinder my performance as an artist?*

Thank you in advance!

Comment: I have two artists nearby - both use Wacom Intuos on Ubuntu 17.10. They love them. Hardware immediately detected upon plugging the USB in, nothing to install, they say it works great.  They also say that creating in Windows is different, but not due to the drawing pad. Size is a matter of your taste.

Comment: Thank you user535733! I am going for the Wacom! Will update this page with the setup and maybe a review! Thanks again!

Comment: Thank you @NerdOfCode for the edit! Learnt a few grammars today!

Comment: Glad I’m good at something @AbdullaMasud!

Comment: @NerdOfCode xD You are more than good!

Comment: Hardware recommendations will often get closed here as opinion based or off-topic. IMHO https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/ would be a better place to ask this question

Comment: Sorry @ElderGeek! Thanks for clarifying the rules and suggesting that page! Will keep that in mind when posting anything like that next time.

Answer (score 0):

I have bought wacom intuos draw. I have to say, it is a great tablet.

Now to the important part. I wasn't able to get my wacom to be detected by Ubuntu 16.04. It shows "No tablet detected". Though the pen works.

I was able to use the pen pressure on Krita (https://krita.org/en/) straight away. But not in InkScape and gimp.

Following codes were used to see if my system detects the tablet:

xinput --list

```
    ⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Wacom Intuos S 2 Pen stylus               id=9    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Wacom Intuos S 2 Pad pad                  id=10   [slave  pointer  (2)]
```

lsusb

```
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 056a:033b Wacom Co., Ltd
```

So, it does detect but something is up.

I have tried troubleshooting. Linking few of them here and also other links I found helpful (This is to help those who are seeing this page. A small quick references):

1. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FMM0n_fuqlA
2. [Ubuntu 14.04. 2 does not recognize my Wacom Intuos tablet draw (ctl-490b)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/685581/ubuntu-14-04-2-does-not-recognize-my-wacom-intuos-tablet-draw-ctl-490b)
3. https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/unity-control-center/+bug/1575887
4. https://medium.com/@ahris/setting-up-wacom-tablets-with-ubuntu-16-04-d7277e4a595d
5. [Wacom Intuos Draw Tablet not detected in System settings and MaptoOutput does nothing](https://askubuntu.com/questions/929971/wacom-intuos-draw-tablet-not-detected-in-system-settings-and-maptooutput-does-no/929991)
6. https://docs.gimp.org/en/gimp-tool-dynamics.html

(please do check elsewhere whether these troubleshooting are safe for you or not. I didn't face any problem. And I also, reverted back to the original settings after troubleshooting didn't help. So, make a backup, or remember the original settings, when ever you can.)

I have moved back to windows, though I believe after sometimes I will eventually find a fix and come back to Ubuntu.

Comment: Upgrading from Ubuntu 16.04 to Ubuntu 18.04 solved the problem for me.